# How can I shrink a Windows 10 partition in dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed. I have only C drive in Windows and I want to shrink it. I'm not able to shrink it and see this error message:

> Windows – Cannot cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located

I disabled Hibernation, PageFile and System protection and after that could shrink it. But it screwed up the Grub and I had to deal with Grub Rescue...

**So, my question is:**
how can I shrink the C drive in dual boot like that?

Comment: You need to do an offline defrag to move those files, there are utilities for that....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/defrag-disk-files-and-system-files-at-boot-time-with-defraggler-v-2-0

Comment: Is it necessary only for dual-boot systems or even if I had only Windows installed?

Comment: @mistery_girl - Is what necessary?  If you want to shrink the system partition, yes, it’s necessary.